# How to convert an HTML string to virtual DOM in React?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I'd like to be able to take a raw HTML string that I insert into a React component via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and have it incorporated into the virtual DOM. Is there any way to do this?

For example, if I have:

```
<Component dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlFromServer}}></Component>
```

how can I get `htmlFromServer` into the virtual DOM? Thanks!

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: A part of my app works by loading raw HTML from a server which then gets stuffed into a React component. I'd like to be able to then work with that HTML that I asynchronously load using React (e.g., use findDOMNode, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Parts of Facebook's React Magic does what you want:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-magic

Answer (score 2):

You can do this natively with [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

E.g.:

```
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlFromServer, 'text/html'),
    body = doc.querySelector('body'),
    div = document.createElement('div');

div.textContent = 'DOM manipulated.';
body.appendChild(div);

return <Component dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: body.innerHTML}}></Component>;
```